# Where is the docker image created on windows 10

Tags: dockerfile, docker-image

I have installed docker 24.0.6 on windows 10. Then following this link https://www.qt.io/blog/2019/03/05/using-docker-test-qt-webassembly I created a simple Dockerfile whose contents are as follows:

```
**FROM trzeci/emscripten** AS qtbuilder

RUN mkdir -p C://TESTY//qtTest//dockerBasedQt
RUN mkdir -p C://TESTY//qtTest//dockerBasedQt//test
WORKDIR C://TESTY//qtTest//dockerBasedQt
```

I simply want to create a folder as of now.

Docker build run completed with no error and I see the following

```
                                                                                                                       1.2s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/trzeci/emscripten@sha256:35bb1dd78e865dbab62fbdd652bab0896917dad5646119d37a4789648e7c187f                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] RUN mkdir -p C://GIT_Repo//qtForWeb//dockerBasedQt                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] RUN mkdir -p C://GIT_Repo//qtForWeb//dockerBasedQt//test                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [4/4] WORKDIR C://GIT_Repo//qtForWeb//dockerBasedQt                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
 => => writing image sha256:76cd1d16e7703ac16ef7d8fe2f0d5b812a4a48b4e9c8f9df5430004c7cf9470f                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/docker_qt_test:1                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s

What's Next?
  View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview
```

But I dont see image file created anywhere.

Docker info says

```
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
```

But I dont have /var on my windows 10 machine.

Where will the image get created?